# datediff calculando somente horario

Tags: php, mysql

Atualmente tenho um código que calcula a diferença de 2 data/hora porém meu calculo só está calculando o horário e caso a data final seja em outro dia a hora não conta +24h e faz somente a diferença do horário como se fosse no mesmo dia. Como eu poderia fazer para calcular todo o período somente o tempo? exemplo:

DtInicial-> 01/10/2019 15:00

DtFinal -> 02/10/2019 10:00

Resultado esperado -> 19:00

Resultado obtido (errado) -> 5:00

```
$resultado_4 = mysql_query($query_4, $conexao);
                      while($dados_4 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_4))
                      {

                        $id_parada = $dados_4 ['id'];  
                        $id_origem_problema =  $dados_4['origem_problema'];
                        $id_classificacao =  $dados_4['classificacao'];
                        $id_tecnologia =  $dados_4['tecnologia'];
                        $id_causa =  $dados_4['causa'];
                        $identificacao = $dados_4['identificacao'];
                        $id_departamentoproblema = $dados_4['departamento'];
                        $contato_local = $dados_4['contato_local'];
                        $sla_operadora = $dados_4['sla'];
                        $data_abertura = $dados_4['data_abertura'];
                        $data_fechamento = $dados_4['data_fechamento'];
                        $id_atendente = $dados_4['usuario'];
                        $contato_local = $dados_4['contato_local'];

                        $dt1 = new DateTime($data_abertura);
                        $dt2 = new DateTime($data_fechamento);

                        $dtAbertura = new DateTime($data_abertura);
                        $dtFechamento = new DateTime($data_fechamento);


                  ?>
                      <tr>
                          <td id = "CC"> <?php echo $id_origem_problema; ?> </td>
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $id_classificacao; ?> </td>
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $id_tecnologia; ?> </td>
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $id_causa; ?> </td>
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $identificacao; ?> </td> 
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $id_departamentoproblema; ?> </td> 

                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo date_format($dtAbertura, 'd/m/Y H:i'); ?> </td> 
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo date_format($dtFechamento, 'd/m/Y H:i'); ?> </td> 
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $contato_local; ?> </td> 

                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $sla_operadora; ?> </td> 
                          <?php
                          $dteDiff  = $dt1->diff($dt2);
                          $dataFormatada = $dteDiff->format("%d %H:%I:%S"); ?>
                          <td id = "CV" style="color: <?php if($dataFormatada <= $sla_operadora) { ?> blue <?php } else { ?> red <?php } ?>  "  > <?php
                            print $dataFormatada; ?> </td>
                          <td id = "CV"> <?php echo $id_atendente; ?> </td> 



                      </tr>
                  <?php
                      }     
                  ?>
```

Comment: UPDATE: problema resolvido via banco de dados.. foi só trazer uma coluna utilizando a função TIMEDIFF( dataInicial, dataFinal) pelo mysql

Answer (score 3):

É uma data que vem de uma base de dados então já deve estar no formato correto, então faça:

```
$dt1 = date_create('2019-10-01 15:00');
$dt2 = date_create('2019-10-02 10:00');
```

e com método `diff` e `format`:

```
var_dump($dt1->diff($dt2)->format("%d %H:%I:%S"));
```

tendo o seguinte resultado:

```
string(10) "0 19:00:00"
```

talvez isso resolva o seu problema inicial, mas, não sei bem o que poderia te ajudar porque o retorno de um método `diff` é um objeto [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php).

Exemplo de um objeto da classe [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php):

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
)
```

[Exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/jZxwAn)

Para calcular dias para horas faça:

```
$diff = $dt1->diff($dt2);
$horas = $diff->h + ($diff->days * 24);
echo "{$horas}  horas e $diff->i minutos";
```

[Exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/1ccc2l)

Comment: a reposta foi útil mas não bem o que eu preciso.. na verdade queria calcular tudo em horas e minutos... por exemplo: diferença de 2 dias.. me traria 48 horas.. e não 2 00:00:00

Comment: Meu amigo @FernandoFefu rapaz o DateInterval lhe dá tudo o que precisa, você falando assim parece que a resposta não tem o objetivo de temporizar ... e tem .. ela te da a diferença em tempos (em qualquer formato só precisa fazer)

Comment: Se precisar transformar dias em horas multiplica por 24 entendeu? @FernandoFefu Eu fiz um exemplo dê uma olhada...